# Error in importing mysql database

Tags: mysql, table-lock

I took dump of a DB from the production. I want to import into my local database

```
mysql -u user_name -p db < db.sql
```

But it shows some error

**ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 25: Can't create table 'table_account' (errno:13)**

And I am unable to import the table. This issue is occurring when I try to Import a particular database. Tried to import some other database. It works fine.

Could anybody solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you get your answer? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes I got the answer. Use '--lock-tables=false' in the import statement

Answer (score 1):

Check the owner of the database directory, may be its the issue..

try this :
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/database_name.

Comment: Does that, still not working only this table has the problem. Tried out importing another one it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create any tables in the database 'mysql'; it is special. Instead CREATE some other DATABASE, and get into it with a USE.

Answer (score 0):

I am re posting the answer I mentioned in the comment for easy accessibility.

Command used ->  mysql -u root -p lock-tables=false db < databackup.sql

Also the below mentioned link will give you more information [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49410/automysqlbackup-lock-tables-false)